# from urllib2 import request - cannot import name request

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, request, urllib2

So i am trying to write a program and i need the module named requests for this, since i am using python version 2.7.9.

i thought using the code:

```
from urllib2 import request
```

would do the job. Yet i get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\NLTKHoofdstuk3.py", line 5, in <module>
    from urllib2 import request
ImportError: cannot import name request
```

I don't get it because i have urllib2 fully working on Python and the module request should be in the module urllib2 (i also don't get an Error when i type "import urllib2")

So does anyone know why my module request is not working but my module urllib2 is

Comment: You're confusing Python 3 with Python 2.

Comment: Is python 3 only having urllib2 with the module request added to it?

Comment: Python 3 has no `urllib2` module but it surely has a `request` module within `urllib`.

Comment: and python 2.7 is having a urllib2 with no request module added to it? If so, what do i need to download to be able to use the request module in python 2.7? or would you suggest to download python 3

Comment: guys there is a Request method for urllib2 in 2.7

Comment: @Ajay There is, but OP is asking for request module not `Request` method.

Comment: @NielsGorsel I am not sure which `requests` module you're looking for, there's a famous external [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module as well.

Answer (score 12):

Try using

```
from urllib2 import Request
```

instead of

```
from urllib2 import request
```

Check the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)

Comment: I still get the same Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib import Request
ImportError: cannot import name Request

Comment: @NielsGorsel it's R in Request and urllib2

Answer (score 11):

Using

```
import urllib;
```

and then

```
urllib.urllopen();
```

For `Python 2.7` you do not need `import` request.

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
import urllib2
```

and use `urllib2` to instead of `urllib.request`

looking at the document https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen
may help more.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 2.7 and encountered the same problem. I was able to solve it after using `urllib3` instead of `urllib` or `urllib2`.

Here's an example screenshot of using `urllib3` working in Python 2.7:
[jupyter_Screenshot_for_urllib3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7lbi.jpg)